# Asterisk - access PBX from internet

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, nat, pbx

I'm behind a firewall with NAT, I can connect from my remote extension and call from LAN to remote, but not reverse. If I call from remote to LAN, nothing happen.

I've forwarded those ports:

```
- SIP 5060
- RTP 10000-20000
```

client get registred correctly.

Need to setup something else?

Answer (score 1):

Very likly you need instruct asterisk about external ip using

```
 externip=1.1.1.1
 localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0; use your net here
```

Also some routers do SIP ALG, on most that work incorrect,so need disable such feature if you find it.